# Python not connect MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Here is the error I am having with Python not connecting to MySQL:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "select.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .network import MySQLUnixSocket, MySQLTCPSocket
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 28, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 12, in <module>
    import select
  File "C:\Python\select.py", line 3, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to ask a proper question, so that people can be helpful with your problem. You might have a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to execute :

```
import mysql.connector # or from mysql import connector
```

Because the module `connector` is only available when you import it explicitly :

```
import mysql

print(dir(mysql))
>>> ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

import mysql.connector

print(dir(mysql))
>>> ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'connector']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you imported the method connector, you simply have to write

```
connector("your connection string")
```